# How to assemble the uberjar jar with bazel?

Tags: dependencies, bazel

I'd like to analyse class dependencies in a Java project build with Bazel. I use (and recommend) [degraph](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/degraph/). degraph takes a jar as an input and generates the class relationships in a graphml file.

How can I generate this monolithic jar with bazel? It seems a BUILD target will only contain the class of it sources. As a result, the better the modularisation, the less information is left for analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<rule_name>_deploy.jar` output of `java_binary` will give you all the classes of the `java_binary` and its dependencies in one jar. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary_implicit_outputs